# glob.glob() returning empty list

Tags: python

I wanted to get the full directory path in a list. The `backup_file_dir` will return `/data/backup-file` and after doing a backup, the backup files will be appended to the above directory, `/data/backup-file/test/test.txt` and `/data/backup-file/test/test2.txt`.

Somehow the backup process will create a subdirectory `test` and when I try to get the full path, it returns empty list `[]`.

```
def compress(backup_file_dir):
    list_files = glob.glob('{}/*/*'.format(backup_file_dir), recursive=True)
    print('list_files--->', list_files)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    backup_file_dir = 'data/backup-file'
    test_cron_schedular = BlockingScheduler()
    test_cron_schedular.add_job(compress, 'cron', hour=1, minute=31, args=[backup_file_dir])
    test_cron_schedular.start()
```

Expected result: `['/data/backup-file/test/test.txt','/data/backup-file/test/test2.txt']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, the following seems to work:

```
list_files = glob.glob('{}/*'.format(backup_file_dir), recursive=True)
```

Printed output:

```
['/data/backup-file/text.txt', '/data/backup-file/text2.txt']
```

Comment: Not sure if it is because I am calling this function using BlockingScheduler. The above function is one of my module/package in `compress.py` and I call this function in `schedular.py` which define like this `bs.add_job(compress, 'cron', hour=hour, minute=minute, args=[backup_file_dir])`. When I execute compress.py itself, i able to get the list of directory path.

Comment: Lawrence: It certainly sounds like it has something to do with using BlockingScheduler.

Comment: Yes sir, I just cant figure out what is the problem of the BlockingScheduler. Just working on it for hours.

Comment: Lawrence: Perhaps the `backup_file_dir` argument isn't being passed to the function correctly — see if you can verify that it's the expected value.

Comment: Sir, I have updated my code above to reproduce the same result. Can you kindly check check out. The result is `list_files---> [ ]` Inside `data/backup-file` got subdir.

Comment: Lawrence: Please try using `glob.glob('{}/*'.format(...` as shown in my answer — **not** `glob.glob('{}/*/*'.format(...`.

Comment: Sir, now it able to print the dir path in the above reproduce script fle. But when I try to call compress func using `schedule.py`, it still returns [ ].

Comment: I have no idea what's different when the scheduler is used, sorry.

Comment: No prob. Appreciate.

Comment: facing the same issue with BlockingScheduler. Any idea on how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
list_files = glob.glob('{}/**'.format(backup_file_dir), recursive=True)
```